# Searching a String Array

Tags: java, arrays

For example if i have a string

```
String [] grades = {"AAAB","ABAA","AABA"};
```

and i want to search the string array to see if any of the students achieved 3 or more A's.

I know that you can search if a string array contains a particular word like:

```
Arrays.asList(grades).contains("AAA");
```

but this does not work if we have something like AABA is there any way around this? Also i want to make it work for all grades not just A..(A,B,C,D etc).

Comment: Store grades as char arrays instead of strings.

Comment: You could do what Anubian Noob said or just make your own custom method. Lopping through the array and then each charAt of the string while having a count variable

Comment: Just loop through the array and examine the String at each index. Stop trying to outsmart your homework.

Comment: You must read about regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate though the String and count the occurences of the given grade:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String [] grades = {"AAAB","ABAA","AABA"};  
        System.out.println(countOccurences(grades[0], 'A'));
    }

    public static int countOccurences(String grades, char gradeToMatch )
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(char grade : grades.toCharArray())
        {
            if(grade == gradeToMatch)
              ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

**Output:** 3

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String [] grades = {"AAAB","ABAA","AABA"};

    for (final String string : grades) {
        final char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();

        int count = 0;
        for (final char c : charArray) {
            if( c == 'A' ) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(count >= 3) {
            System.out.println("3+ A Grades");
        }
    }
}
```

The main thing here is the call `string.toCharArray()`. That gives you a character array from the string so you can loop through and count the number of A grades in the array.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to iterate through a given string and count how many times a grade appear.

```
public int countGrades(String grades, char g) {
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
        if (grades.chatAt(i) == g)
            c++;

    return c;
}
```

Also, you should consider to use a array of chars instead just a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean checkGrades(String grades, char someGrade, int times) {
    int counter=0;
    for (int k=0;k<grades.length();k++) {
        if (grades.charAt(k)==someGrade) counter++;
        if (counter>=times) return true;            
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course this works only if you grades are composed by a single character. You can apply the function to the entire array:

```
    for (String g : grades) {
        System.out.println(checkGrades(g, 'A', 3));
    }
```